# how to add a response header which name is JSESSIONID when the server response set-cookie

Tags: spring-boot, session-cookies, samesite, embedded-tomcat-8, cookie-httponly

I want to add JSESSIONID as headers entry when the server response set-cookie, to replace of cookie to keep the session of server and client, is any way to do it?
my application is springboot 1.5.9, very old, but I cannot upgrade it, if the springboot later version has any resolution, also be helpful.

I tried to reaponse in a filter, but every request it will response, not like set-cookie, if no way to do it, I think try to override the TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory as a bean can be useful, I have already to do this to set the SameSite=None and override sessionid parse method for my project.